# how to profile android app developed using kony platform?

Tags: android, profiling, temenos-quantum

I have android app developed using Kony Platform.
Will this app get detected in DDMS and can be profiled(memor, tracelogs) using the DDMS tools ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes this app will be detected by DDMS. You can see logs.

Comment: But am unable to do memory profiling. PLease let me know how to do memory usage/memory leak analysis of android app developed using Kony